# Calculating coordinates range by given distance

Tags: coordinates, distance

I have a database with cities and it's coordinates (latitudes and longitudes). And I have a function which calculates a distance between two cities:

```
function getDistanceBetweenPoints($latitude1, $longitude1, $latitude2, $longitude2)
{
    $theta = $longitude1 - $longitude2; 
    $distance = ( sin( deg2rad($latitude1) ) * sin( deg2rad($latitude2) ) ) + ( cos(deg2rad($latitude1) ) * cos( deg2rad($latitude2) ) * cos( deg2rad($theta) ) ); 
    $distance = acos($distance); 
    $distance = rad2deg($distance) * 111.18957696;

    return round($distance); 
}
```

But now I need a function which calculates a second coordinates range, based on first coordinates (for a given city) and radius (in kilometers). For example: I pick up some city (and it's coordinates) and specify a range of 100km. And I want to know what cities from my database are in this range.

I tried to transform this formula from given function, but I don't know how to get range of coordinates.